# mysql crashed(mysql has gone away) while getting gmail api data and storing it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

while getting data from from gmail and storing it in a databas. mysql database always crashes. here is the latest log from the latest crash

```
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-07-28 15:50:10 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-07-28 15:50:11 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-07-28 15:50:11 3708 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 980584530 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-07-28 15:50:11 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.35-80.0 started; log sequence number 980584530
2017-07-28 15:50:12 12048 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-07-28 15:50:12 3708 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.22-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2017-07-28 15:51:37 2b10  InnoDB: Error: space id and page n:o stored in the page
InnoDB: read in are 2259217641:2609242579, should be 0:379!
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [Note] InnoDB: Log sequence number at the start 3113380305 and the end 3923956440 do not match.
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corruption: Block in space_id 0 in file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 corrupted.
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: Based on page type PAGE TYPE CORRUPTED (55158)
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: Space 0 file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 read of page 379.
2017-07-28 15:51:37 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
2017-07-28 15:51:37 2b10 InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex (lots of hex that follows)
InnoDB: End of page dump
2017-07-28 15:51:38 2b10 InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 1165101849, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 455176142, innodb 202543763, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 3577157157, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 455176142, innodb 1083534192, none 3735928559, page LSN 736093480 3113380305, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 3923956440, page number (if stored to page already) 2609242579, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 2259217641
InnoDB: page type 55158 meaning PAGE TYPE CORRUPTED
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: It is also possible that your operatingsystem has corrupted its own file cache.
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the error.
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page you can also try to
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: fix the corruption by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html about forcing recovery.
2017-07-28 15:51:38 11024 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
2017-07-28 15:51:38 2b10  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 11024 in file buf0buf.cc line 4829
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170728 15:51:38 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=4
max_threads=1001
thread_count=4
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787106 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
InnoDB: page type 42674 meaning PAGE TYPE CORRUPTED
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: It is also possible that your operatingsystem has corrupted its own file cache.
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the error.
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page you can also try to
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: fix the corruption by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html about forcing recovery.
2017-07-28 15:54:19 2400 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
2017-07-28 15:54:19 960  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2400 in file buf0buf.cc line 4829
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170728 15:54:19 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
```

here is the table that i was trying to insert to

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
    `id_email` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fk_lead` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `sender` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `sender_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `sender_email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `recipient` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `recipient_email` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `recipient_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `gmail_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `thread_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `received_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `subject` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `content` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `deprecated` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_updated` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_agent` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `mime_version` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `content_type` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `originating_ip` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_email`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `gmail_id` (`gmail_id`)
)
```

i think the culprit is the base_64 content that my script is trying to insert to the table's column 'content'.

so everytime i try to run my script, this always shows in the logs. 
this mysql server is installed together when i installed XAMPP for windows 10 64bit. btw, i am running this on a laptop with average specs (i5 7200u, 8gb ram, 512gb ssd).

Comment: if there is base_64 content, why don't you set that field blob? This might solve your problem.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz it's because the content might just contain plain text. some emails are just plain text. i can put the base_64 on a new column but that means recoding a big part of the system which is currently live and on production. i am just adding a part and testing on my local machine

Comment: this topic might solve your problem as well. Give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071309/mysql-crash-on-startup