# XAMPP-MYSQL crashes

Tags: mysql, crash, xampp

I have a problem with MySql on Xampp. It crashes after has been launched. My SO is Windows 10 on a Macbook Pro with Bootcamp. The used port is 6528. The system establishes a connection (the left indicator became green) and after a moment crashes.

```
2019-01-18 10:44:30 a38 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-01-18 10:44:30 a38  InnoDB: Operating system error number 6 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
 InnoDB: Operation close to file d:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc and at line 2493
2019-01-18 10:44:30 2616 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'close' returned OS error 206. Cannot continue operation
190118 10:44:30 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL crash on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071309/mysql-crash-on-startup)

Comment: I think this is not a question for SO. you should do what the message says: *To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs*

Comment: The duplicate has a other OS but the same `mysqld got exception 0x80000003` error.. If that does not work do what @Jens suggested.